# Multiple Word Anagram with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, anagram

I have been playing with this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ck8gH/2/) from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24085190/make-anagrams-generator-in-javascript-finding-only-words-contained-in-a-list) but can't figure out 1) how to get it to work with multiple words such as if I input

> applebanana

to get the output

> apple banana, banana apple

2) And so that if I change the variables to include multiple word strings like:

```
var dictionary = [
"apple",
"banana",
"orange",
"pear",
"mandarin orange" ];
```

that I can input

> mandarinorange

to get the output

> mandarin orange

Here is the relevant code from the JSFiddle above

```
var maxCount = 10000;
var dictionary = [
    "apple",
    "banana",
    "orange",
    "pear",
    "watermelon"
];

function isValidWord(word) {
    for(var i = 0, n = dictionary.length; i < n; i++) {
        if(word === dictionary[i]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

/**
Generates all of the anagrams using a dictionary and an exclusion list read from
an HTML form.
*/
function runAnagramGenerator(anagramString, excludesString, tout) {
    var excludes = getExclusionList(excludesString);
    var anagrams = [];
    generateAnagrams("", anagramString, excludes, anagrams);
    //Remove duplicates
    uniqueAnagramList = anagrams.filter(function(elem, pos, self) {
        return self.indexOf(elem) == pos;
    });
    console.log('Anagrams: ' + uniqueAnagramList.length);
    tout.value = "";
    for(var i = 0, n = uniqueAnagramList.length; i < n; i++) {
        tout.value += uniqueAnagramList[i] + "\r\n";
    }
}

function getExclusionList(excludesString) {
    var excludes = [];
    if (excludesString != "") {
        var excludesArray = excludesString.split(",");
        for(var i = 0, n = excludesArray.length; i < n; i++) {
            excludes.push(new RegExp(excludesArray[i]));
        }
    }
    return excludes;
}

function generateAnagrams(prefix, postfix, excludes, resultArray) {
    if(resultArray.length >= maxCount) return;

    if (postfix == "") {
        var meetsConditions = true;
        if(isValidWord(prefix) === false) meetsConditions = false;
        for(var i = 0, n = excludes.length; i < n; i++) {
            if(prefix.match(excludes[i]) != null) {
                meetsConditions = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(meetsConditions) {
            resultArray.push(prefix);
        }
    }
    for(var i = 0, n = postfix.length; i < n; i++) {
        var prefix2 = prefix + postfix.charAt(i);
        var postfix2 = postfix.substring(0,i) + postfix.substring(i+1);
        generateAnagrams(prefix2, postfix2, excludes, resultArray);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the question instead just linking to an external resource.

Answer (score 0):

1) Change isValidWord to containsValidWord, and rewrite the logic slightly

2) If you ever have a remaining prefix that consists only of whitespace, you have a match